# Performing a Segue from a table with searchbar to an UIImage in Detail View in xcode

Tags: xcode, uiimage, segue, searchbar

I'm pretty new to xcode so I'm having trouble performing this task.  I've created a table with a search bar with names that are passed to a detail view with a UILabel that shows the corresponding name of the cell clicked.  The search bar works and it filters the results.  I used this tutorial to help me with it:

http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/

Now I want to have an image in the detail view instead of a UILabel, that corresponds to each of the cells but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that.  Here is the code I'm working with:

TableViewController.h:

```
@interface SearchViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

TableViewController.m:

```
@interface SearchViewController ()

@end


@implementation SearchViewController {
    NSArray *cards;
    NSArray *searchResults;}

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    cards = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
             @"Snivy",
             @"Servine",
             @"Serperior",
             @"Tepig",
             @"Pignite",
             @"Emboar",
             @"Oshawott",
             @"Dewott",
             @"Samurott", nil];

}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [cards filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [cards count];
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SearchCardCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [cards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }



    return cell;}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowSearchCard"]) {
        SearchCardViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

        if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            destViewController.cardName = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            destViewController.cardName = [cards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ShowSearchCard" sender: self];
    }
}
```

UIViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cardLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cardName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *searchCardDetail;
```

UIViewController.m:

```
@implementation SearchCardViewController

@synthesize cardLabel;
@synthesize cardName;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    cardLabel.text = cardName;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

So in detail, the "cards" are the names in the table. Right now, it segue to a UILabel of the name of the card and I would like to have it instead, segue to the corresponding image of the card in the regular table and filtered table when searched.  I appreciate your time and help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understanded your question correctly, but I would use one of these three approaches:

1st:
Easiest way is to follow [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/improve-detail-view-controller-storyboard-segue/)

2nd: Create custom cell which you will use instead of default cell. To get you on track, you can check this good tutorial [How to create custom cell](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/). In your custom cell, you'll declare additional variable, UIImage, which will or won't be displayed in your table view. Point is, you can send it in *prepareForSegue* method to your detailViewController.

3rd: Create *NSDictionary* where you will have values (images of your items) for keys (name of item). Then, pass it in *prepareForSegue* to your NSDictionary in detailViewController. After that, just assign your UIImage to UIImageView in your detailViewController based on what name of item did you receive. (So you'll still be sending name and then detailImage = [yourdict objectForKey:myItemName];)

I'm writing this on my windows laptop, because I'm not at work right now (that's where I have my mac mini), so there may be some syntax errors in my answer :)